# python os.system force computer restart input from user for how long delay should be

Tags: python

```
import os
time = int(input("How many seconds do you want to delay restart?"))
chkdsk = "chkdsk /f C:"
restart = "shutdown -r -t ????" ####My problem is right here, how do i get
#the time input into that command
canrestart = "shutdown -a"
os.system(chkdsk)
os.system(restart)
print("Press enter key to cancel restart")
input()
os.system(canrestart)
```

I put where I am having my problem in the code with ##### I was asking how do I take the users input and then put it into the restart command.

from the comments I was able to get `restart = "shutdown -r -t %d"% time` to work

Comment: are you just asking how to format a string?

Comment: please explain what is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
restart = 'shutdown -r -t %d' % time
```

?

Also, raw_input is generally preferable over input -- it's safer. input() will evaluate anything the user types.

Comment: I tried restart = 'shutdown -r -t %ds' % time but it didnt work, %d did however.